# Python: Removing duplicates in numpy array and keeping order

Tags: python, arrays

I have an numpy array that looks like this:

```
[array([1.4600e-01, 2.9575e+00, 6.1580e+02]), array([5.860e-01, 4.507e+00, 8.748e+02]), array([1.4600e-01, 2.9575e+00, 6.1580e+02]), array([5.860e-01, 4.507e+00, 8.748e+02]), array([9.6900e-01, 1.7822e+00, 1.0829e+04]), array([  0.701 ,   1.6545, 603.3   ])]
```

I want to remove duplicate arrays so that the result looks like this:

```
[array([1.4600e-01, 2.9575e+00, 6.1580e+02]), array([5.860e-01, 4.507e+00, 8.748e+02]),  array([9.6900e-01, 1.7822e+00, 1.0829e+04]), array([  0.701 ,   1.6545, 603.3   ])]
```

I have tried `list(set(my_array))` but it does not work on numpy arrays. `np.unique()` does not preserve the order and rearranges values from least to greatest, which is **not** what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```py
array = np.array
a = [array([1.4600e-01, 2.9575e+00, 6.1580e+02]), array([5.860e-01, 4.507e+00, 8.748e+02]), array([1.4600e-01, 2.9575e+00, 6.1580e+02]), array([5.860e-01, 4.507e+00, 8.748e+02]), array([9.6900e-01, 1.7822e+00, 1.0829e+04]), array([  0.701 ,   1.6545, 603.3   ])]

seen = set()

ans = []
for i in a:
    arr = np.array([]) 
    for j in i:
        if j not in seen:
            arr = np.append(arr, j) 
            seen.add(j)
        else:
            continue
    if arr.any():
        ans.append(arr)
ans
```

if you want to remove array-wised:

```py
seen = set()
ans = []
for i in a:
    if tuple(i) not in seen:
        ans.append(i)
        seen.add(tuple(i))
ans
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your code correctly, if my array is called `my_array`. Would I replace `a` in the main for loop with `my_array`?

Comment: `a` is your raw data, yes you can

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if there are common values in arrays but the arrays aren't identical. For example, change the first value from `1.4600e-01` to `2.4600e-01` and that causes the third array to be replaced with `array([0.146])`.

Comment: @sj95126, I thought it is element-wise remove duplicated, otherwise just move `seen=set()`

Comment: The question looks to me like removing entire arrays if they're a duplicate of another entire array.